# reporting success events in omniture

Tags: adobe-analytics

Trying to track how many visistors who don't log in see the popup box that prompts them to create an account, and then each subsequent page of that popup box (java lightbox).

I have these tags in the box coding (the vendor implemented it):

```
s.prop4=Login Success
event19 = Already Registered
s.eVar20=Non-registered

Conversion flow ->

event20 = Welcome
event22 = Stop
event23 = Login
event24 = Plan Options
event25 = Create Account
event26 = Confirm Print Address
event27 = Enter Payment
event28,purchase=Transaction Complete
```

and then in Omniture I have put everything in its respective place, but I feel like i am missing something.  I get a custom conversion report that shows how many got the login success vs the non-registered but none of the events past that.

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi Chrisa, I am assuming this is for a web app. A good option maybe to use a traffic variable (prop like pageName) as that will give you pathing and counts, maybe segment of anonymous users. Can you explain a bit more about what you want to see in the reports. C.

Comment: this sounds like a problem with the implementation. Can't really help without seeing code or the site in question. I suggest you contact the vendor that implemented it

Comment: Crayon Violent:
if you go to http://www.goupstate.com/ after you view 5 stories a green box pops up.  I want to track how many times this box is seen, and the subsequent pages of the box.

Comment: Chris de Groot: it's for a subscribe now popup box on a newspaper site.

We are looking to see how many people see that box.  Once they see it do they login or continue to the next page of the registration process and subsequent pages til they complete a transaction at the end.

Comment: @ChrisaChangala if you do `@username` when responding someone then they will be notified that you responded. Otherewise there's no way for other users to know you responded to them and you have to hope they wander back in the door! Anyways, I went to the site and went to 5 articles (clicking links in the most read/emailed/recent box on the right of the page) and I didn't get a popup

Comment: @CrayonViolent Thanks!
did you go on a desktop or mobile?  Yaay for another bug to squash!

Comment: desktop, windows 7, firefox latest

Comment: Seems to be but you can always check the the forum.The forum is a great place to bounce ideas off other users and get live feedback.  http://adobe.ly/1juTbTO